# How to give back groundcolor to widget?

Tags: qt

i my qt application i have a window and i set the background color of the window as white using "Change stylesheet'when i placed a button its background color is also the white.....i want the green window with button with a background color of grey...how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the  *autoFillBackground* property to *true* on the widget.
Otherwise the background color, you have selected, will have no effect.

If this is not the case, please write a better description of the problem.